# Passing options to a program: what's the convention for one dash vs two?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal

Some programs will take options like this:

```
$ someprogram -orange apple
```

And other programs will use something like this:

```
$ otherprogram --orange apple
```

Is there a "rule" or convention for this in Linux/Unix/OSX?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The most common is GNU `getopt` style, with one dash for short options and two dashes for long options.

---

- Initially, Unix programs took single-letter options preceded by a single dash and optionally bundled:

  ```
  ls -laF

  ls -l -a -F
  ```

  The two commands above are equal.

  When an option takes a value, it overrides bundling: In `gpg -aofoo.gpg`, `-a` and `-o` are options and `foo.gpg` is the value given to `-o`.
- Most of them did, anyway.

  [`tar cvzf`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&manpath=Unix+Seventh+Edition) is a common sight. Current versions accept `tar -cvzf` too, and depending on whether you add the dash the arguments will be interpreted in very different ways. For example, these two mean the same thing (note how dashless options are *not* immediately before their value):

  ```
  tar -xf file.tgz -vzO /etc/passwd /var/backups
  ```

  ```
  tar xfvzO file.tgz /etc/passwd /var/backups
  ```

  [BSD `ps`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&manpath=4.4BSD+Lite2) always uses `-`; [SysV `ps`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&manpath=Unix+Seventh+Edition) never does. The Linux version accepts both versions and changes its behavior depending on whether an option was prefixed with a dash. (Unlike tar example above, ps changes the option *meanings* as well.)
- X11 programs used long options preceded by a single dash or sometimes a plus sign:

  ```
  xterm -class FooTerm +vb -u8
  ```

  This sets options `class` and `u8`, and *unsets* the `vb` option.

  X11 style is incompatible with option bundling.
- Later, long options were added to GNU `getopt()` in a way that's compatible with one-letter options.

  ```
  gpg -se --no-armor --output=signed.gpg
  ```

  This sets `-s`, `-e`, and `--no-armor` (which is opposite to `--armor`).

  Usually, `--output=signed.gpg` and `--output signed.gpg` are equivalent. (But not always – e.g. curl does not accept the former, only the latter.)

  (If I recall correctly, long options used `+` as the prefix before it was changed to `--`.)
- The POSIX specification has a section [Utility Argument Syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), which describes the one-character options.

---

Most Windows programs use their own parsers, driving users mad.

- Some require `/a /b /c`, others allow VMS-style `/a/b/c`, yet others prefer Unix-style `/abc`.
- Most use `/` as prefix, some also accept `-`, others accept *only* `-`.
- Values can be given as `/foo bar`, `/foo=bar`, `/foo:bar`.
- Usually spaces can be `/quoted "like this"`, but some programs take the `"` as a literal character. (This is a downside of letting the program do its own word-splitting; in Unix this is handled by the shell.)
- Cross-platform programs may use an implementation of `getopt`.

Comment: You forgot `find` - probably the most familiar use of single-dash long options.

Comment: @Dennis: Feel free to edit =)

Comment: You got System V and BSD `ps` backwards; consider that Linux refers to the `-`-less options as BSD compatible, and OSX used a stock BSD `ps` until Tiger, when it added SVID style `ps` and then made it the default in Leopard with BSD style selectable by environment variable.  And until I got used to it (having originated in the System III/V side of things) FreeBSD kept tripping me up with `ps`.

Comment: Regarding quotes, what do you mean by "in Unix this is handled by the shell"? The program receives '"like' and 'this"' as arguments, only using e.g. `getopts` will fix this. Did you mean `like\ this`?

Comment: @geekosaur: I based my post on the manual pages from two historical systems, [4.4BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&manpath=4.4BSD+Lite2) and [Seventh Edition Unix](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&manpath=Unix+Seventh+Edition), both of which are linked to from the post and confirm that the BSD version used a dash. See also [FreeBSD 8](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE).

Comment: @Daniel: No. In any Unix shell, `"foo bar"`, `'foo bar'`, and `foo\ bar` will all result in a single 7-character string `foo bar` being added to the `argv` array. Quoting and word-splitting is always handled by the shell _before_ calling `exec()`. I tested. (It is *Windows* that passes the unparsed command line to programs via `CreateProcess()`.)

Answer (score 5):

Generally the first is found in older programs which are too well entrenched to change.  Those kind of long options are incompatible with the standard `getopt()` function.

The second style was introduced by GNU `getopt_long()`, and is compliant with existing standards which expect the first style to be bundled short options (that is, `-orange` is expected to mean `-o -r -a -n -g -e`).  This style of long option is strongly preferred.

Comment: The convention as far as I have seen is to have all options available as --word and the most commonly used options as -x -y -z etc as well as --word

Comment: Right.  That's supporting POSIX/SVID-style options as well as long options; the first style (used mainly by programs from the X11 distribution) isn't compatible.

Comment: Those pesky X11 options - they should be taken outside and shown the toe of my boot - repeatedly.